# New Order Send custom email template in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, orders, email-templates, after-plugin

I have two condition :-

- First if customer is not approve send custom email template.
- Second if customer is approve send magento default email template.

How can i achieve this.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Magento **`Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender`** from the email template for orde.

If you want customization then you have to work on **prepareTemplate()** method.

You need to override this class.

**Here Code:**

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\MagentoModule\Model\Order\Email;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\IdentityInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;

class Sender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Template $templateContainer,
        IdentityInterface $identityContainer,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Renderer $addressRenderer)
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $templateContainer,
            $identityContainer,
            $senderBuilderFactory,
            $logger,
            $addressRenderer);
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Populate order email template with customer information.
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareTemplate(Order $order)
    {
        $this->templateContainer->setTemplateOptions($this->getTemplateOptions());

        if ($order->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            $templateId = $this->identityContainer->getGuestTemplateId();
            $customerName = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
        } else {

            //  do customization at here
            $isApproved = $this->isCustomerApproved($order->getCustomerId());
            if($isApproved){
                $templateId = 'Your Template id';
            }else{
                $templateId = $this->identityContainer->getTemplateId();
            }

            $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
        }

        $this->identityContainer->setCustomerName($customerName);
        $this->identityContainer->setCustomerEmail($order->getCustomerEmail());
        $this->templateContainer->setTemplateId($templateId);
    }
    private function isCustomerApproved($customerId)
    {
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
            if($customer->getData('customer_approved')){
                return true;
            }
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException | LocalizedException $e) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help me on this question :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/340530/85907

Answer (score 1):

@Amit Bera is great answer but i have describe more.

Using preference override Model file.Below steps
**`/app/code/Stack/Exchange/etc/di.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Dependency injector xml file
*
* @author Mohit Patel
*/
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="Stack\Exchange\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender"/>
</config>
```

After set file in **`di.xml`**.You can create OrderSender file in your model folder like :-

**`/app/code/Stack/Exchange/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php`**

```
<?php

namespace Stack\Exchange\Model\Order\Email\Sender;

use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as PaymentHelper;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\Template;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order as OrderResource;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;

class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerFactory;

    protected $emailTemplate;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Email\Model\BackendTemplate $emailTemplate,
        Template $templateContainer,
        OrderIdentity $identityContainer,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\SenderBuilderFactory $senderBuilderFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        Renderer $addressRenderer,
        PaymentHelper $paymentHelper,
        OrderResource $orderResource,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $globalConfig,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager)
    {
        // exit("Mohit Patel");
        parent::__construct($templateContainer, $identityContainer, $senderBuilderFactory, $logger, $addressRenderer, $paymentHelper, $orderResource, $globalConfig, $eventManager);
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->emailTemplate = $emailTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Populate order email template with customer information.
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @return void
     */
    protected function prepareTemplate(Order $order)
    {
        parent::prepareTemplate($order);

        $this->templateContainer->setTemplateOptions($this->getTemplateOptions());

        if ($order->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            $templateId = $this->identityContainer->getGuestTemplateId();
            $customerName = $order->getBillingAddress()->getName();
        } else {
            $email_template = $this->emailTemplate->load('Customer Approve Pending New Order', 'template_code');
            $customerDisTemplate  =  $email_template->getId();
            // die("Mohit Patel");
            //  do customization at here
            $isApproved = $this->isCustomerApproved($order->getCustomerId());
            if($isApproved){
                $templateId = $this->identityContainer->getTemplateId();
            }else{
                $templateId = $customerDisTemplate;
            }

            $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
        }

        $this->identityContainer->setCustomerName($customerName);
        $this->identityContainer->setCustomerEmail($order->getCustomerEmail());
        $this->templateContainer->setTemplateId($templateId);
    }
    private function isCustomerApproved($customerId)
    {
        try {
            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
            $isApprove = $customer->getApproveAccount();
            if($isApprove){
                return true;
            }
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException | LocalizedException $e) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In above code i have add two condition like if customer is not approve send other custom email template otherwise send default magento email template.Hope this help other.

**`THANKS.`**